# How many CAL needed for SQL server

Tags: sql

Just wish to know, if I have only created one user login under SQL server however several people uses an application that uses that single ID to communicate with the database. Would this situation requires only one user CAL?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're referring to Microsoft SQL server, each user or device that connects to the SQL server requires a CAL unless the server is licensed with a Core based license, see [Microsoft SQL Licensing Guide](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&sqi=2&ved=0CFIQFjAC&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/3/C/73CAD4E0-D0B5-4BE5-AB49-D5B886A5AE00/SQL_Server_2012_Licensing_Reference_Guide.pdf&ei=WpqjU9TFBqeqsQSE2oGQBQ&usg=AFQjCNHdiY7wTdgDJKB9TgNDmeZr1A7BbA&sig2=nKpmnpcSHWTfaXRNRbKJug&bvm=bv.69411363,d.cWc)(PDF).  It does not matter if they are all using the same login to connect, such as an application using a single SQL authentication account.

If you have multiple SQL servers and they are all CAL-licensed, then the same user CAL's can be used to access multiple servers as long as the CAL is the same or higher version than the SQL server.

Comment: SqlACID, is the administrative account to SQL Server considered as a "user" needing a CAL ? Frankly speaking, even 5 years later, this CAL stuff is really painful. No presales/hotline/support from Microsoft on that matter...

Comment: lol things have not changed, probably worse. I would ask for a licensing expert at Microsoft. The sa admin account per se would not need a CAL but if users are using an application that uses that account to connect to SQL (which is a bad idea obviously), then each of those users would need CALs.